# Self referencing many to many relationships in Fluent NHibernate automapping

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

The title pretty much explains it all, I have a Member object that references 'Friends' who are also type Member.

```
 public class Member : Entity
    {
        public Member()
        {            
            Friends = new List<Member>();
        }

        public virtual IList<Member> Friends
        {
            get; set;
        }
     }
```

The schema generation tool makes it a 1:n relationship while it should be a n:n relationship i.e. a column is added to the member table called member_id and no connecting table is created.

Is there any way to make a Self referencing many to many relationships in Fluent NHibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely possible. You just need to create an override

```
public class MemberOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Member>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Member> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasManyToMany(m => m.Friends)
               .Table("MemberFriendsLinkTable");
               .ParentKeyColumn("MemberId")
               .ChildKeyColumn("FriendId");
    }
}
```

Just tell the auto mapping configuration where your overrides are to have these included.

EDIT: Updated to include Parent and Child key columns

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I added your code and I get "NHibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection: Proj.BO.Member.Friends column: Member_id" is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @Eitan, did you figure it out?

Comment: As it seems, you have to specify the ParentKeyColumn and the ChildKeyColumn explicitly, as shown in the following article: http://thelongwayback.wordpress.com/2010/08/25/fluent-nhibernate-object-referencing-instance-of-itself-self-referencing/